# Using an external Python library in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to use [`trading_ig` 0.0.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trading_ig/0.0.5) in some Python code I am writing. Can anyone tell me how to add this code to my library? I have run:

```
$ pip install trading_ig
```

But I still can't import when running code, for example:

```
from trading_ig import IGService

from trading_ig_config import config
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same version of Python on the command line and within your PyCharm project (for example, if you set up a virtual environment, did you `activate` it on the command line)? Have you tried installing the package through the PyCharm GUI (or does it already appear in the list of installed packages)?

Comment: How do I find a list of installed packages?

Comment: It should already be there if you are using the correct interpreter for your project.

Comment: Ah ok I will check tonight Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by the following steps,

1) PyCharm > Preferences... > Project Interpreter > Python Interpreters

2) Click "Create Virtual Environment" and pick your base interpreter.

3) Click "Install" and install any packages you need. You can also add other repositories if the default ones do not contain required libraries. Another benefit is that you can see which libraries have newer version and can be updated.

Please refer: [PyCharm and external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883768/pycharm-and-external-libraries)

Comment: Rather than copy across (some of) the content of an existing answer, please comment/flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok jonrsharpe hereafter I will do that. Thanks :)