# Why won't PyCharm see my libraries?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, libraries

If I do something like "import selenium" (or any other kind of third party library) in a .py file and then run it from the terminal, it works just fine. But if I make a new file in PyCharm CE and do the same thing, it can't find the library / module.

How can I fix this or get it to point in the right location? I use a Macbook Pro.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883768/pycharm-and-external-libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to setup your project in PyCharm to use the Python interpreter that has your libraries:

Go to: `file->settings->project->project interpreter`

And select the appropriate interpreter from the dropdown. After selecting an interpreter, the window displays a list of libraries installed on that interpreter; this should further help you make the right selection.

Comment: I do not see "project interpreter" anywhere

Comment: That worked. Can accept in 8 min. Can I set this as a Pycharm-wide thing or do I have to re-set this for every new Project?

Comment: You can set a *Pycharm-wide* interpreter in `File->Default Settings`

Answer (score 2):

I've faced a similar issue on Pop!_OS after installing PyCharm via Flatpak. I think the installation is somehow incomplete, as I've had these issues (among others):

- Installer could not create the menu shortcut due to the lack of credentials. Unlike during a typical installation, it wouldn't ask for the password and instead I had to uncheck that option altogether.
- Built-in terminal defaulted to `sh`. Even after changing to `bash`, it would not read my `.bashrc` and many commands were missing.
- After changing the interpreter into a local `virtualenv`, it would just default to Python 3.7 (even though the version was actually 3.8) and it didn't see any of my installed libraries.
- When I've tried to use a Docker Compose environment, IDE failed to detect Docker Compose installation.

I've eventually uninstalled PyCharm and downloaded it directly from Jetbrains website to make it work correctly.